# Regrex Extract special Strings from text

Tags: r, regex, stringr

My problem looks like this:

```
data_example <-
  c("Creditshelf Aktiengesellschaft / Key word(s): Forecast/Development of Sales\n\ncreditshelf Aktiengesellschaft",
    "Swiss Life Holding AG / Key word(s): 9 Month figures\n\nSwiss Life increases fee income by 13%",
    "tonies SE / Key word(s): Capital Increase\n\ntonies SE: tonies successfully places 12,000,000 new class A shares",
    "init innovation in traffic systems SE / Key word(s): Contract/Incoming Orders\n\ninit innovation in traffic systems SEs")
strings_to_extract <-
  c("Key word(s): Word1/Word2",
    "Key word(s): Word1/Word2 Word3",
    "Key word(s): Word1 Word2 Word3",
    "Key word(s): Word1/Word2/Word3",
    "Key word(s): Number Word1/Word2",
    "Key word(s): Number Word1 Word2",
    "Key word(s): Word1 Number Word2")
```

There will always be a whitespace or a "/" to separate them.
My try looks like this:

```
str_extract(data, "Key word[[:punct:]]{1}s[[:punct:]]{2} [[:alpha:]]{1,}|Key word[[:punct:]]{1}s[[:punct:]]{2} [[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:punct:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}Key word[[:punct:]]{1}s[[:punct:]]{2} [[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:punct:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:punct:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}")
```

I mean I capture a good part of theme, but I think its too complicated.
Could somebody give me a advice how to do it better?

Thx amd KR

Comment: What are you trying to extract here?  You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What is the expected output for this data?

Comment: Is "Number" a word or is it numbers like 1234?

Comment: Thx. I postet an example

Answer (score 3):

You can  use

```r
str_extract(data, "Key word\\(s\\):\\s*\\w+(?:\\W+\w+){1,2}")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yw2uY8/1).

*Details*:

- `Key word\(s\):`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:\W+\w+){1,2}` - one or two sequences of one or more non-word chars followed with one or more word chars.

Answer (score 1):

Your example data makes a different approach suitable as well, as your keywords always end at `\n`.

In this case you could just do:

```
data_example <-
c("Creditshelf Aktiengesellschaft / Key word(s): Forecast/Development of Sales\n\ncreditshelf Aktiengesellschaft",
  "Swiss Life Holding AG / Key word(s): 9 Month figures\n\nSwiss Life increases fee income by 13%",
  "tonies SE / Key word(s): Capital Increase\n\ntonies SE: tonies successfully places 12,000,000 new class A shares",
  "init innovation in traffic systems SE / Key word(s): Contract/Incoming Orders\n\ninit innovation in traffic systems SEs")

stringr::str_extract(data_example, "Key word\\(s\\):.+(?=\\n)")
#> [1] "Key word(s): Forecast/Development of Sales"
#> [2] "Key word(s): 9 Month figures"              
#> [3] "Key word(s): Capital Increase"             
#> [4] "Key word(s): Contract/Incoming Orders"
```

`Key word\\(s\\):` matches `Key word(s):`, and `.+(?=\\n)` matches all characters: `.+` which are succeeded by `\n`: `(?=\\n)`. Notice the double escapes (`\\`) which are needed in R.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include phrase "Key word(s): ", then you can do following:

```
data_example <-
  c("Creditshelf Aktiengesellschaft / Key word(s): Forecast/Development of Sales\n\ncreditshelf Aktiengesellschaft",
    "Swiss Life Holding AG / Key word(s): 9 Month figures\n\nSwiss Life increases fee income by 13%",
    "tonies SE / Key word(s): Capital Increase\n\ntonies SE: tonies successfully places 12,000,000 new class A shares",
    "init innovation in traffic systems SE / Key word(s): Contract/Incoming Orders\n\ninit innovation in traffic systems SEs")

stringr::str_extract(string = data_example,
                     pattern = '(?<=Key word\\(s\\): )[\\s\\S]+')

#> [1] "Forecast/Development of Sales\n\ncreditshelf Aktiengesellschaft"                        
#> [2] "9 Month figures\n\nSwiss Life increases fee income by 13%"                              
#> [3] "Capital Increase\n\ntonies SE: tonies successfully places 12,000,000 new class A shares"
#> [4] "Contract/Incoming Orders\n\ninit innovation in traffic systems SEs"
```